# Ссылка не работает без "/" в конце

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-плагины

Значит такая проблема:
при вызове https://url/check получаю ошибку 301
а при вызове https://url/check/ все отлично работает, но мне нужно чтоб работала https://url/check , и да сайт на вордпресс, но эта ссылка не имеет дело с моим сайтом.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

решил задачу таким образом:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: а что в .htaccess?

Comment: @Yakoffka <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: И это правильно! Ничего не трогай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решен:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/ -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в пермалинках убрать слеш в конце и затем смотреть конфиги вашего сервераю

Comment: я решил проблему, спасибо

Comment: @androidx реши "проблему" - напиши решение.

Answer (score 0):

не уверен, но попробуйте заменить четвертую строку:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: не помогло, но я решил проблему, спасибо